# The link to the source of my question leads to a 404 error

Tags: support, bug, questions, markdown

[In the revision history of my question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/5265/revisions), the link [**source**](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/684a2106-2010-4968-b364-543ddc3d8c66/view-source) for the last version of my question gives a 404 error.

I have found no direct working way to have the source of the last version of my question.

- Can someone repair that ?
- In the meantime, can someone give me the source of the last version of my question ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the source from the link that was showing a 404... it is likely expected to be an HTTP 404 error since the question was deleted by the system, but I'm still checking

```
I am planning to make this network :

      ⎡ Internet modem ⎤      ⎡     Wi-fi      ⎤ <--> [ PC ]     
      ⎢       &        ⎥ <--> ⎢  access point  ⎥                 
      ⎢     router     ⎥      ⎢   as bridge    ⎥ <⋅⋅> [ Mac 1 ]  
      ⎣   (Freebox)    ⎦      ⎣ (Time Capsule) ⎦ <⋅⋅> [ Mac 2 ]  

The wi-fi access point will be connected to the router in (gigabit) Ethernet.

I am interested in the wi-fi communications between the Macs.

Let’s say I send a big file from Mac 1 to Mac 2.

<a href="http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110882/do-the-wi-fi-communications-from-mac-to-mac-travel-through-the-access-point">It seems that the Macs have to send and receive the waves through the access point. [By the way, expert advice on this question would be appreciated.]</a>

Is this (crazy) enough, or do the communications have to go through the router too ?
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mike. Some Unicode characters look broken, but I will do with that.

Comment: We'll see if we can find an answer for that too.  Unless someone else jumps in, it make take several days